# How to save all images included in css code?

Tags: css, web-scraping

i have a website with a css style and i want to save all the images that is inside the CSS file.

Example we have site.com/style.css
Inside we have:

```
.class {
    background-image: url(/img/icons/recent.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the hardcore solution that i found is:

- Download a style and edit it
- replace all

  url("/
  with url("http:/site.com/
- [extract all](https://www.browserling.com/tools/extract-urls) links from a style
- download all links with a download manager
- delete all  *");*